# Examples of sequences in $l_p$ spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

While working, I came out with a sequence $x_k=(\frac{-2}{r})^k$ and $y_k=(-2-r)^k$ where $0<r<1.$
After calculation I came to the conclusion that $x_k$ and $y_k$ do not belong to the $l_p$ spaces. However I am not sure about the result. Please help me confirming the result.

Comment: The general term $x_k$ does not converge to zero as $k \to \infty$, so ... Idem for $y_k$

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 In fact it is not bounded as $k\rightarrow \infty$. You need that stronger criterion for $p=\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\sum |a_n|^{p}$ to be finite it is necessary that $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. In your examples this condition is not satisfied so the sequences do not belong to $l^{p}$ for any $p \in (0,\infty)$. They also do  not belong to $l^{\infty}$ since $|a_n| \to \infty$ in both cases.

Comment: Can we say that $x_k$ and $y_k$ are not bounded as well?

Comment: @Yanko Thanks for the comment. I have now included the case $p=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you @KR Murthy and Yanko...

Comment: @TajaYaying Yes, they are unbounded. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: This solves my confusion... Thanks @KR Murthy.